# Cross Domain Access Policy not working for silverlight hosted in IIS

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, crossdomain.xml, clientaccesspolicy.xml

My silverlight application is currently hosted in IIS and is set up to only use HTTPS.

the silverlight web project is the root of the IIS website and the webservices project is a seperate web application mapped to /Services.

I can navigate to my site by using "" and  ""

but if I use the second option the site loads fine but I get an error when attempting to access any of my services.

> An error occurred while trying to make
>   a request to URI
>   'https://localhost/Services/Services/Authentication.svc'.
>   This could be due to attempting to
>   access a service in a cross-domain way
>   without a proper cross-domain policy
>   in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may
>   need to contact the owner of the
>   service to publish a cross-domain
>   policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.
>   This error may also be caused by using
>   internal types in the web service
>   proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute

I have  Crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml files in the root of my Web Services application and also within the root of the Silverlight Web project.

**Crossdomain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain- policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="https://*" secure="true" />
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**clientaccesspolicy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
      <policy>
  <allow-from>
    <domain uri="https://*"/>
  </allow-from>
  <grant-to>
    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
  </grant-to>
</policy>
```

I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Thanks

**Edit**

The following is the what fiddler shows after calling the service. .

[image: Fiddler Output]
With fiddler set up to decode https IE didn't show any extra entries, but with chrome I get the following output

[image: Fiddler Output2]

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, "This **could be** due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way..." Try using some tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com) in the client to see what is the actual response from the server. That will give you more information about the issue.

Comment: I've edited my post to show the fiddler output can't see anything.

Comment: You need to explicitly tell Fiddler to decode HTTPS traffic (Tools -> Fiddler Options -> HTTPS), otherwise it won't show the HTTPS requests.

Comment: I've set that up now and I get 1 extra entry in fiddler and it has no information within it.

Comment: I've updated the original post with information displayed by fiddler when i tested with Chrome. It looks like it is looking for the correct file and finding it then failing on the service call. When connecting through chrome using Https://Localhost the error returned is "Not Found" if i connect using IE or Chrome using the IP then the error is the error in my initial post. I've set up breakpoints within the service and attached VS to the process but the calls are not hitting the server.

Comment: The service is returning a 500 (Internal Server Error). If there is any information in the response from Fiddler, then it may give a hint on what the problem is; otherwise you can enable tracing at the server, and in the trace logs it will have an exception explaining why the server returned a 500 response.

Answer (score 0):

As shown by fiddler your reference file for the service are having pointers to localhost:444 this usually happens when you have both projects in same solution and add the service reference.

Comment: The web services are hosted on https://Localhost:444 the silverlight application is hosted on Https://Localhost:443 so the references are correct

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by right clicking on the frontEnd.Web part of my solution, going to properties and then the Web tab, instead of using an auto assign port option, I changed it to use local IIS server. This got rid of the error.